# Get parameters from referrer

Tags: url, request

Is there a way to get the parameters from the referrer url?

I've tried this:
`{{ craft.request.urlReferrer.getQuery }}`
but that’s not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with some Twig code:

```twig
{% set referrer = craft.request.urlReferrer %}

{% if referrer %}
    {# Remove everything before the `?` #}
    {% set queryString = referrer|replace('/^.*\\?/', '') %}

    {# Split the query string into individual params #}
    {% set params = queryString|split('&') %}

    {% for param in params %}
        {# Split this param on the `=` sign #}
        {% set parts = param|split('=') %}
        {% set name = parts[0] %}
        {% set value = parts[1] is defined ? parts[1] %}

        {# Do something with it... #}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Note that this could would require Craft 2.2 or later, which comes with a regex-enabled [replace](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#replace) filter.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! Had an inkling that this would require some regex wizardry, that world does somewhat scare me though...
Clever breadcrumbs here I come, woooooo!

Comment: @Katrin The regex bit wasn’t totally necessary, just saved a couple additional lines of code :)